# After Effects scripts: How to add Composition with start time display to an Composition

Tags: javascript, after-effects

I have three compositions (`compFinal`, `compSlide1` and `compSlide2`).

I have used a script to add `compSlide1` and `compSlide2` to the `compFinal` composition.

I use the following code to add the compositions:

```
compFinal.layers.add(compSlide1); 
compFinal.layers.add(compSlide2);
```

But when inserting them in `compFinal` both compositions `compSlide1` and `compSlide2` will have the same start-time "0".

When adding composition `compSlide2` I want it so that I can set the start-time displayed for composition 2 equal the end-time of `compSlide1`

[image]

Comment: Check the scripting guide. Search for 'startTime' http://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It will depend partly on the complexity of your layers, but you can use the `startTime` property of current layer combined with the `outPoint` to adjust the layers to follow each other.

A simple loop can help in that regard, run after all the layers are added (in order):

```
// initial time (in seconds)
var time = 0;

// loop through all layers in comp
for(var i = 1; i <= finalComp.layers.length; i++) {

    // set layer startTime based on current time value
    finalComp.layers[i].startTime = time;

    // update time to hold outPoint time of this layer
    // which will next layer's start time
    time = finalComp.layers[i].outPoint;
}
```

If you only have two layers just set the second layer to start from previous layer's out-point:

```
finalComp.layers[2].startTime = finalComp.layers[1].outPoint;
```